# two tables of same size tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, pgfplots

I am creating two tables with the following code (tikz package}

```
    \documentclass[twoside,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\confmatrix}{
\matrix (conmat) [row sep=.01cm,column sep=.01cm, ampersand replacement = \&] {
\node (tpos) [box, align = center,
    label=left:\( \mathbf{P'} \),
    label=above:\( \mathbf{P} \)
    ] {True  Positive \\ (tp)};
\&
\node (fneg) [box, align = center,
    label=above:\textbf{N},
        ] {False  Negative \\ (fn)};
\\
\node (fpos) [box, align = center,
    label=left:\( \mathbf{N'} \),
        ] {False  Positive \\ (fp)};
\&
\node (tneg) [box, align = center,
        ] {True  Negative \\ (tn)};
\\
};
\node [rotate=90,left=.01cm of conmat, text width=2.5cm,align=center,anchor=center] {\textbf{Actual Label}};
\node [above=.01cm of conmat] {\textbf{Predicted Label}};
}

\newcommand{\costmatrix}{
\matrix (costmat) [row sep=.01cm,column sep=.01cm, ampersand replacement = \&] {
\node (tpcos) [box, align = center] {$0$};
\&
\node (fncos) [box, align = center] {$1+\beta^2-t$};
\\
\node (fpcos) [box, align = center] {$t$};
\&
\node (tncos) [box, align = center] {$0$};
\\
};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=footnotesize}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Contingency Table}[.4\textwidth]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={draw,rectangle,text width=1.5cm,align=left}]
\confmatrix
\end{tikzpicture} }
\subcaptionbox{Cost Matrix}[.3\textwidth] {
\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={draw,rectangle,minimum size =1cm,text width=1.5cm,align=left}]
\costmatrix
\end{tikzpicture} }
\caption{Binary Classification}
\label{fig:conf_cost_mat}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

My problem is, the tables are not of same size. I want both tables to be of same size.

Comment: Please, could you write a complete example, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. These commands doesn't work for me but i don't know what's missing in my code compared with yours.

Comment: modified the question with MWE

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

You have to fix equal minimum size to equivalent columns and rows in both matrices to obtain similar sizes. Otherwise, first column of `costmat` is adjusted to its size which is narrower than first column in `conmat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{box/.style={draw, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm}}

\newcommand{\confmatrix}{
\matrix (conmat) [draw, row sep=.01cm,column sep=.01cm, ampersand replacement = \&] {
\node (tpos) [box, align = center,
    label=left:\( \mathbf{P'} \),
    label=above:\( \mathbf{P} \)
    ] {True  Positive \\ (tp)};
\&
\node (fneg) [box, align = center,
    label=above:\textbf{N} ] {False  Negative \\ (fn)};
\\
\node (fpos) [box, align = center, label=left:\( \mathbf{N'} \) ] {False  Positive \\ (fp)};
\&
\node (tneg) [box, align = center ] {True  Negative \\ (tn)};
\\
};
\node [rotate=90,left=.01cm of conmat, text width=2.5cm,align=center,anchor=center] {\textbf{Actual Label}};
\node [above=.01cm of conmat] {\textbf{Predicted Label}};
}

\newcommand{\costmatrix}{
\matrix (costmat) [draw, row sep=.01cm,column sep=.01cm, ampersand replacement = \&] {
\node (tpcos) [box, align = center] {$0$};
\&
\node (fncos) [box, align = center] {$1+\beta^2-t$};
\\
\node (fpcos) [box, align = center] {$t$};
\&
\node (tncos) [box, align = center] {$0$};
\\
};}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\confmatrix

\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]
\costmatrix
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]